# Formatar Double com duas casa

Tags: java, double

Estou tratando um arquivo `.csv` com um *id*, *valor (1,214.45)* e preciso formatar uma soma final desses valores com apenas duas casas após a virgula.

**Desenvolvi o seguinte trecho do codigo:**

```
`DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
    for(Integer i : filiais) {
        Double soma = 0.0;
        int contador = 0;
        for(String s : list) {
            String[] arr = new String[2];
            arr = s.split(",");
            if (arr[0].equals(i.toString())) {
                soma += Double.parseDouble(arr[1]);
                contador++;
            }
        }
        String aux = df.format(soma);
        somaFiliais.add(Double.parseDouble(aux));
        contadorFiliais.add(contador);
    }`
```

**Tenho o seguinte erro:**

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "53010,77"
>     at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
>     at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
>     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
>     at Exercicio1.gerarRelatorio(Exercicio1.java:57)
>     at Exercicio1.main(Exercicio1.java:26)
> ```

Comment: Para utilizar o `Double.parseDouble` é necessário substituir a vírgula pelo ponto (na variável `aux`)

Comment: direto no numero? não sei como fazer...

Comment: lembrei, usei o .replaceAll, muito obrigado Valdeir!!

Comment: Se conseguiu resolver com o `replaceAll` seguindo a sugestão do @ValdeirPsr, aproveite e coloque como resposta de forma a poder ajudar futuros leitores.

Comment: @A.Fernando, tem um motivo especial para usar Double? Em geral é melhor usar BigDecimal.